# Slide tab bar like in android market

Tags: java, android, android-activity, slide, google-play

Does anyone know how to implement the bar like in android market (Categories, featured, top paid...) I've also seen it in the new version of SuperUser so i know it can be done. Thank you for your responses!

Comment: ViewPager from v4 compat library + fx: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: Thank you! That was it, I didn't know it was called ViewPager.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html - how to do it in the google manier

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to Selvin for the response.

See as suggested:
https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

or this for a quick tutorial:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

Answer (score 1):

Jake Wharton's Android-ViewPagerIndicator is a good option, but ***it doesn't support underline bar movement*** like below images(you can see what "underline bar movement" is as video at [here](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html#scrollable)).

I think [*Astuetz's PagerSlidingTabStrip*](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) is an another good option for this regard, since it gives more natural and interactive user experience.

This implementation is available at Github.
See: https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

Also you can download sample app at [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.sample).

[image]   [image]

Comment: "it doesn't support underline bar movement", is there's any way to support the underline movement using Jake Wharton's ?

Comment: @ralphspoon AFAIK, there isn't. You can find it by checking their source code.

Comment: yeah thanks, guess I'll stick with slidingtabstrip, thanks though :)

Comment: Also, I found a good "official" sample here, https://github.com/googlesamples/android-SlidingTabsColors.