# How to create label tabs for horizontal paging similar to google offers app

Tags: android, menu, tabs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Slide tab bar like in android market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502988/slide-tab-bar-like-in-android-market)

I'm trying to figure out how to do tabs similar to the way google offers does it. I can't seem to find a way to do it yet I've seen it in several applications.

[image of google offers tabs]

[image: https://lh6.ggpht.com/lYR4ylcxSviK5rDJVRe-Zi6H7QwxaTb9gUrZUBWPTWkjIKbQPEdDQq19CKxKL2YpPg]

and on the android website[image]

Scroll down to where it says horizontal paging

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above answer, if you're using Fragment you can try to use the combination of ViewPager and Jake Wharton TitleIndicator project library.

read ViewPager [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

find TitleIndicator [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)